# Change element in Jquery datepicker

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, datepicker

Good day all,

I have follow this website (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to create a datepicker using jQuery.

The datepicker was successfully created, however, my datepicker is not fully same as the datepicker in the website. The following is my screen shot :

Datepicker in the website:

[image]

Datepicker in my environment:

[image]

In my environment, I do not have the "Left" and "Right" icon. I have tried to edit the `js` file and the `css` file, however, it doesn't take effect.

Start edit here : I just found out 1 things few hours ago.

When I write my code as follows, it works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

However, if I copy those code and put in my physical folder, and I change the href url as follows, the left and right icons are gone:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
```

I copy 100% of the `css` code and paste it correctly, named it correctly, path correctly, not understand why I get that problem.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I get what is the problem.

The problem is, I need to download an `png` file which is call `ui-icons_222222_256x240.png`, and then put it into a folder name `images`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you already have your custom css that is overriding the datepicker css values. You just need to declare the date picker CSS at the bottom of your cascade i.e just after your CSS and your things will work just fine.